# Is the inception training working for unbalanced dataset? (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I wonder if the code here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

for fine-tuning the inception network, is working for an unbalanced dataset. The sample dataset is flowers which contains 5 classes of the same number of pictures. Is it working for a dataset with different number of pictures in each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inception architecture is like any other neural network architecture and will work reasonably well on sets with unbalanced datasets, regression or even segmentation. Still the network will probably be more skewed to the pictures, which are more prevalent in the training set. So I would advise you to do an equal split per class.

However if this is not possible you can still expect a reasonable solution with an inception network.

Comment: I am working on binary classification problem and the one class contains more images that's why I asked. Thank you very much.